# Помогите составить регулярное выражение для парсинга json в зависимости от переменной на PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Как правильно при помощи регулярных выражений на PHP извлечь из json значение конкретного ключа, зная значение другого ключа?
Имеется некоторая переменная $request, в которую можно записать, например, image1, и надо записать в другую переменную $result значение ключа value, т.е. blue. (см. пример ниже)

```
  {
   "value": "blue",
   "name": "image1"
  },
  {
   "value": "green",
   "name": "image2"
  },
  {
   "value": "red",
   "name": "image3"
  }
```

Помогите составить такое регулярное выражение.

```
 <?php 

$data = '{   "value": "blue",   "name": "image1"  },  {   "value": "green",   "name": "image2"  },  {   "value": "red",   "name": "image3"  }';

preg_match(('?<="value": ").*(?="[^}]+?image3'), $data, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);

 ?>
```

Comment: Прочитайте описание метки [tag:регулярные-выражения]. Надо привести конкретные примеры текстов и что в них надо найти, чтобы можно было однозначно составить регулярку. Парсинг json по каким-то переменным скорее всего надо делать соответствующими инструментами

Comment: Мне нужно сделать, чтобы если пользователь водил в textbox image1, то получал бы результат blue, image2 – green и т.д. Скорее всего, здесь надо использовать что-то типа (.*?), но я плохо разбираюсь в регулярных выражениях. Ведь надо как-то туда ещё и переменную засунуть, ту, в которой значение из текстбокса (то, что ввёл пользователь)

Comment: Вы точно прочитали мой комментарий?

Comment: Да, прочитал. Я же в первом посте указал пример кода, который полностью аналогичен тому, который я использую и написал более подробно, что мне требуется сделать. Извините, если я Вас не понял.

Comment: Надо декодировать json в массив, а не изобретать бессмысленные костыли.

Comment: То есть, через json_decode? А как правильно выводить из него, допустим, значение blue, если мне нужен image1?

Comment: Ну серьезно, декодируй свою json-строку в массив, посмотри на структуру массива и подумай как получить что-то из массива (подсказка - `foreach`).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Находит значение ключа `value`, когда далее есть какой-то `image`:

```
(?<="value":\h").*(?="[^}]+?image)
```

Тест https://regexr.com/5a302

> {
>
> "value": "**blue**",
>
> "name": "image1"
>
> },
>
> {
>
> "value": "**green**",
>
> "name": "image2"
>
> },
>
> {
>
> "value": "**red**",
>
> "name": "image3"
>
> }

Сгенерированный код:

```
$re = '/(?<="value": ").*(?="[^}]+?image)/m';
$str = '  {
   "value": "blue",
   "name": "image1"
  },
  {
   "value": "green",
   "name": "image2"
  },
  {
   "value": "red",
   "name": "image3"
  }';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111733/discussion-on-answer-by-dim0n------).

Comment: Не стесняемся пояснять минусы и/или смотреть в чат сначала

Answer (score 0):

Можно же просто использовать `json_decode` и `foreach`:

```
$data = '[{   "value": "blue",   "name": "image1"  },  {   "value": "green",   "name": "image2"  },  {   "value": "red",   "name": "image3"  }]';
$arr = json_decode($data, true);
$value = "";
foreach ($arr as $row)
{
    if ($row["name"] == "image1")
    {
        $value = $row["value"];
        break;
    }
}
echo $value;   // blue
```

Comment: Почему-то выдаёт ошибку: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in W:\domains\localhost\index.php on line 5

Comment: Потому что json в примере невалидный, должен быть `[{}, {}, {}]`, обновил ответ.